# NEW APK is not replaced with Previous APK on Developer Console

Tags: android, apk

We have uploaded APK to Google Console while ago for In-App Purchase testing. Never published and currently Draft in prod. We just finished up the developing and tried to upload FINAL APK to Production. However, New APK is not replaced with Previous APK and never uploaded. Note that No error displayed and it tells "Current Production APK will be deleted" once New APK is uploaded [Find Attachments]

No error but not uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the code

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
```

in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file?